# C# automation - Method to loop through tabs to access the page depending on test case

Tags: c#, automation, webdriver, automated-tests

I want to create a reusable method in C# which I can add to my Helper class which would allow me to access a tab depending on the parameter

I use Page Factory and speckflow as framework in visual studio

I would like to pass a string of the tab name as a parameter. Reason for this is that if the tab change, or is the order changes or a tab name is renamed I would not have to change the code

This works but looking to see if anyone has something more robust

```
public static void DashBoardTabSelect(string tabName)
        {
DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'" + tabName + "')]")).Click();
        }
```

I would be grateful for any help

Please see screenshot below which shows the tab and also the elements

[example of tabs and page elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4TDI.png)